# Simulated Annealing vs SGD with (warm) Restarts

Tags: optimization, stochastic-gradient-descent, simulated-annealing

What's the difference between simulated annealing and stochastic gradient descent with restarts? They both seem like they are occasionally going backwards at a decreasing rate. Also what is the difference between SGD with restarts and with warm restarts?